# Geographical distribution and use of "Enhorabuena"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I consider myself a near-fluent Spanish speaker, having learned it primarly in Mexico. I have never heard the term "Enhorabuena" used there; of course, I realize that this doesn't mean that it **isn't** used. Is it commonly used across the Spanish-speaking world, or is limited to certain countries? If I wanted to say "Congratulations on buying this thing!" or "Congratulations on achieveing your goal!" does it sound ok to use "enhorabuena" or is "felicidades" better, for a world-wide audience?

Comment: I perfectly understand _«enhorabuena»_ and I think it is more appropiate than _«felicidades»_ in this context.  However I would seldom use it and I'm not completely sure if everyone around me, particularly the younger generations, will understand it.

Comment: yo entiendo «enhorabuena» aunque la mayoria de las veces que la he escuchado a sido a personas mayores o en las novelas

Comment: Thanks all for your answers and comments. It's hard to pick an "answer" because I guess my question was asking more for an opinion than a definitive answer. Nonetheless, I will pick one answer. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: This is what I've found on Facebook recently: "Muchas Felicidades Plantel 56... Un saludos afectuoso al Profe. Luis Enrique. En hora buena Felicidades".
The guy who posted this was not older than 20, living in Fortín de las Flores in the state of Veracruz ..

Comment: Enhorabuena is used in Puerto Rico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the first time I have ever heard of "Enhorabuena", but I did a little bit of research.

According to [Spanish-Only.com](http://www.spanish-only.com/2008/11/spanish-word-day-enhorabuena/)

> First all, there is a difference between the two. It’s a small difference, but there’s one. Second of all, you use felicidades when it’s someone’s birthday. Can you use enhorabuena as well? No! Don’t fall in the trap to use in this context. Also, when someone graduated or passed a test enhorabuena is used instead of felicidades. For the rest, you can use both words pretty much for the same things.
>
> -Excerpt from [Spanish-Only.com](http://www.spanish-only.com/2008/11/spanish-word-day-enhorabuena/).

Some examples that [Spanish-Only.com](http://www.spanish-only.com/2008/11/spanish-word-day-enhorabuena/) gave was:

1. Tengo que darte la enhorabuena. (I must congratulate you.)
2. ¡Enhorabuena!(Congratulations!)

Other sources:

[Yahoo! Education](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dict_en_es/spanish/enhorabuena) (Define)

[Congratulations: felicidades vs. felicitaciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/congratulations-felicidades-vs-felicitaciones) from [Spanish StackExchange](http://www.spanish.stackexchange.com). (Mentioned)

Answer (score 10):

'Enhorabuena' is standard language usage in Spain. It is used mainly for personal achievements, while 'Felicidades' is more for something that has happened to you. So we use 'Enhorabuena' for a promotion, a degree, a marriage or a baby, while Felicidades for birthday, Christmas or winning the lotto.

Despite this, 'Enhorabuena' is receding and 'Felicidades' is seeing its usage increase.

Comment: Same here (Argentina)

Comment: Thanks for this reply, it was really instructive. I picked the other reply as the "answer" because of the links and references, but yours was a close second. :)

Comment: I'd add that enhorabuena is more formal and felicidades more informal. You can use enhorabuena to congratulate someone for a recent wedding, but you surely use felicidades if the person is close to you. Also you can use felicidades to congratulate someone for a new employ, but if it's not a close relative to you you surely will better use enhorabuena.

Answer (score 3):

In response to a geographical distribution, here in Chile it is absolutely not used. I have never said it nor heard it. It is very common in Spain. But if you use it in Chile, I think a certain percent of the population will understand you.

Always remember that Spanish varies from country to country, dictionary and main directives are in [RAE](http://www.rae.es). Different meanings for different regions are indicated there.

Comment: +1... why the downvote? I think it's good answer.

Comment: Because my English is not good enough i guess. Anyway this is a Spanish Language exchange knowledge site, I am sure i can help on it.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Mexico, we use "felicidades" to congratulate someone for something.

Despite almost anyone would understand if you say "enhorabuena", it just sounds weird.